# Traverse through all sub nodes of two different XML nodes in a single xslt

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0, transformation

Node1:

```
<retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLPOAP/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetail/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLPOAP/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetail/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess">
<client:promotions>
<client:promotion>
<client:id>139</client:id>
<client:name>P_499_Wolverine</client:name>
<client:Description/>
<client:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</client:activationDt>     <client:expiryDt/>
</client:promotion>
<client:promotion>
<client:id>71</client:id>
<client:name>Free XYZP</client:name>
<client:Description/>
<client:activationDt>2016-01-29T15:30:58+08:00</client:activationDt>
<client:expiryDt>2017-06-01T00:00:00+08:00</client:expiryDt>
</client:promotion>
</client:promotions>
</retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse>
```

Node2:

```
<processResponse xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/KPProductsAPI/KPProductsAPI"        xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/KPProductsAPI/KPProductsAPI">
<ns3:promotions>
<ns3:promotion>
<ns3:id>139</ns3:id>
<ns3:name>KP_MHP_499_Wolverine_KP</ns3:name>
<ns3:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</ns3:activationDt>
</ns3:promotion>
<ns3:promotion>
<ns3:id>140</ns3:id>
<ns3:name>PQR_XYZ_499_Wolverine_KP</ns3:name>
<ns3:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</ns3:activationDt>
</ns3:promotion>
</ns3:promotions>
</processResponse>
```

Expected output:

```
<output>
<promotions>
<promotion>
<id>139</client:id>
<name>KP_MHP_499_Wolverine_KP</name>
<activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</activationDt>
</promotion>
<promotion>
<id>71</id>
<name>Free XYZP</name>
<Description/>
<activationDt>2016-01-29T15:30:58+08:00</activationDt>
<expiryDt>2017-06-01T00:00:00+08:00</expiryDt>
</promotion>
</promotions>
</output>
```

These two nodes are inputs to my xslt. My output xml should contain all promotions in "retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse" and if any promotion id matches with promotion id in "processresponse" details of promotion in "processresponse" should be selected. For the above given Node1 and Node2 (input to xslt). Can anyone please help me out in achieving this?

Tried this but no luck :( :(

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/"
            xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20"
            xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:ns2="http://www.abs-c.com/LoggingVariables"
            xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions"
            xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/"
            xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
            xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/LFProductsAPI/LFProductsAPI"
            xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
            xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension"
            xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator"
            xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLMVNE/MVNERetrieveSubscriberDetail/MVNERetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess"
            xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction"
            xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc"
            xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue"
            xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath"
            xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype"
            xmlns:med="http://schemas.oracle.com/mediator/xpath"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
            xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath"
            xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk"
            xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/ParsingTwoNodesSample/BPELProcess1"
            xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension"
            xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap"
            exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns2 plnk soap ns3 wsdl client ns0 xsd ns1 ns4 bpws xp20 bpel bpm ora socket mhdr oraext dvm hwf med ids xdk xref ldap" >
<xsl:param name="Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload"/>
<xsl:key name="cust" match="ns3:promotion" use="ns3:id"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<ns4:processResponse>
<ns4:subscribers>
<ns4:Subscriber>
<ns4:promotions>
<xsl:for-each  select="/client:retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse/client:subscribers/client:Subsc riber/client:promotions/client:promotion/client:id">
<!--<xsl:for-each    select="$Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload/ns3:processResponse/ns3:promotio    ns/ns3:promotion/ns3:id">-->
<xsl:variable name="lf" select="key('cust', .)"/>
<ns4:promotion>
<ns4:id>
<xsl:value-of select="$lf/ns3:id"/>
</ns4:id>
<ns4:name>
<xsl:value-of select="$lf/ns3:name"/>
</ns4:name>
</ns4:promotion>
</xsl:for-each>
</ns4:promotions>
</ns4:Subscriber>
</ns4:subscribers>
</ns4:processResponse>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Please post minimal but complete code snippets allowing us to reproduce the problem. Showing XSLT without namespace declarations is pointless. As for the code, the `<xsl:variable name="lf" select="key('cust', .)"/>` should probably be `<xsl:variable name="lf" select="key('cust', ., $Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload)"/>`

Comment: Thanks .Updated with the namespaces @Martin Honnen

Comment: See http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAV for a partial solution. You will have to add the elements that are missing and you will have to decide which data to output if there is no match, as it happens with `71` in your sample data.

Comment: Thanks . If there is no match we need to output data in Node1

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:bpws="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/03/business-process/" xmlns:xp20="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.Xpath20" xmlns:bpel="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/process/executable" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ns2="http://www.abs-c.com/LoggingVariables" xmlns:bpm="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpmn20/extensions" xmlns:plnk="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2003/05/partner-link/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/KPProductsAPI/KPProductsAPI" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:ora="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension" xmlns:socket="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.adapter.socket.ProtocolTranslator" xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLPOAP/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetail/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess" xmlns:mhdr="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.mediator.service.common.functions.MediatorExtnFunction" xmlns:oraext="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.pc.services.functions.ExtFunc" xmlns:dvm="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.dvm.LookupValue" xmlns:hwf="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/workflow/xpath" xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsbpel/2.0/plnktype" xmlns:med="http://schemas.oracle.com/mediator/xpath" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ids="http://xmlns.oracle.com/bpel/services/IdentityService/xpath" xmlns:xdk="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension/xpath/function/xdk" xmlns:xref="http://www.oracle.com/XSL/Transform/java/oracle.tip.xref.xpath.XRefXPathFunctions" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/ParsingTwoNodesSample/BPELProcess1" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.oracle.com/bpel/extension" xmlns:ldap="http://schemas.oracle.com/xpath/extension/ldap" exclude-result-prefixes="xsi xsl ns2 plnk soap ns3 wsdl client ns0 xsd ns1 ns4 bpws xp20 bpel bpm ora socket mhdr oraext dvm hwf med ids xdk xref ldap">
    <xsl:param name="Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload">
        <processResponse xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/KPProductsAPI/KPProductsAPI" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/KPProductsAPI/KPProductsAPI">
            <ns3:promotions>
                <ns3:promotion>
                    <ns3:id>139</ns3:id>
                    <ns3:name>KP_MHP_499_Wolverine_KP</ns3:name>
                    <ns3:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</ns3:activationDt>
                </ns3:promotion>
                <ns3:promotion>
                    <ns3:id>140</ns3:id>
                    <ns3:name>PQR_XYZ_499_Wolverine_KP</ns3:name>
                    <ns3:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</ns3:activationDt>
                </ns3:promotion>
            </ns3:promotions>
        </processResponse>
    </xsl:param>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="cust" match="ns3:promotion" use="ns3:id"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns4:processResponse>
            <ns4:subscribers>
                <ns4:Subscriber>
                    <ns4:promotions>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="//client:promotions/client:promotion"/>
                    </ns4:promotions>
                </ns4:Subscriber>
            </ns4:subscribers>
        </ns4:processResponse>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="client:promotions/client:promotion[key('cust', client:id, $Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload)]">
        <xsl:variable name="ref" select="key('cust', client:id, $Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload)"/>
        <ns4:promotion>
            <ns4:id>
                <xsl:value-of select="$ref/ns3:id"/>
            </ns4:id>
            <ns4:name>
                <xsl:value-of select="$ref/ns3:name"/>
            </ns4:name>
        </ns4:promotion>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="client:promotions/client:promotion[not(key('cust', client:id, $Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload))]">
        <ns4:promotion>
            <ns4:id>
                <xsl:value-of select="client:id"/>
            </ns4:id>
            <ns4:name>
                <xsl:value-of select="client:name"/>
            </ns4:name>
        </ns4:promotion>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

transforms the input

```
<retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse xmlns:client="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLPOAP/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetail/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess" xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/SBLPOAP/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetail/POAPRetrieveSubscriberDetailProcess">
<client:promotions>
<client:promotion>
<client:id>139</client:id>
<client:name>P_499_Wolverine</client:name>
<client:Description/>
<client:activationDt>2015-05-10T02:37:16+08:00</client:activationDt>     <client:expiryDt/>
</client:promotion>
<client:promotion>
<client:id>71</client:id>
<client:name>Free XYZP</client:name>
<client:Description/>
<client:activationDt>2016-01-29T15:30:58+08:00</client:activationDt>
<client:expiryDt>2017-06-01T00:00:00+08:00</client:expiryDt>
</client:promotion>
</client:promotions>
</retrieveSubscriberDetailResponse>
```

into the output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:processResponse xmlns:ns4="http://xmlns.oracle.com/Custom/ParsingTwoNodesSample/BPELProcess1">
   <ns4:subscribers>
      <ns4:Subscriber>
         <ns4:promotions>
            <ns4:promotion>
               <ns4:id>139</ns4:id>
               <ns4:name>KP_MHP_499_Wolverine_KP</ns4:name>
            </ns4:promotion>
            <ns4:promotion>
               <ns4:id>71</ns4:id>
               <ns4:name>Free XYZP</ns4:name>
            </ns4:promotion>
         </ns4:promotions>
      </ns4:Subscriber>
   </ns4:subscribers>
</ns4:processResponse>
```

Adapt that on your own to add the other elements you want in the output, it is merely meant to show you how to use a key to cross-reference the elements and check if there is one.

Comment: I am facing the following error **XML-22000: (Error) Error while parsing XSL file (Expected ')' instead of ','.).**  . I think it is because I am trying to pass 3 params to key function.

I am passing Invoke2_process_OutputVariable.payload (i.e, Node2  ) as parameter to my xslt.

Comment: Well, if you don't have an XSLT 2.0 processor then you can't use XSLT 2.0 and the code I posted is XSLT 2.0. The code is at http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAV/2 and there works fine without giving any error.